# Adding text to variables that already contain text

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, mp3

I'm attempting to create a music player in Python 3.5.2 and I'm having trouble making it so users won't have to put the exact filepath for the music they wish to play. This is the code I am experimenting with:

```
import os    
Minput= input("Insert exact path of mp3: ")    
os.startfile(Minput)
```

I'm confused on how I would go about making this code so that the user would only input the name of the MP3, not the exact filepath.

In order to play an MP3 file now, a user would input 'MP3_folder\example.mp3'.

Comment: if the path always remains the same you can append it on your own,rather than user adding it.

Comment: It does always stay the same, the user would move their song into the MP3_folder and then be able to play it from the program. Hopefully all they would have to input is the name of the file.

Comment: can you try constant_path ="root_path"; Minput= input("Insert file name "); Minput  = constant_path+"\"+Minput  ;
os.startfile(Minput);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use relative pathing. You will need your users to specify the starting point (typically the directory in which the app was started). The user would then use `./` to represent that directory or `../` to reference the directory above. These can be applied multiple times so `../../` would reference the directory above the directory above the current one. AFAIK all of python's built in file libraries support this by default so it should just work

Comment: Would there be a way to automate this process in the code? The pathway should always stay the same, the only variable is the name of the mp3 file. I'm wanting it so that all the user would have to input is 'example' and the song would play.

Comment: You could just prepend the full path to the variable after receiving input fron the user or prepend `./`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to get it to work using the following code.  `Minput= input("Insert name of mp3: ")

os.startfile("MP3_folder\\" +Minput + ".mp3")`